# R: Order variables / columns in a data frame by their attributes

Tags: r

I have a data frame with hundreds of variables. Each variable has a numeric attribute. I would like to order the variables based on their numeric attributes.
Imagine the following data frame:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(v1=c(1,2,3),v2=c(1,2,3),v3=c(1,2,3))

attributes(df$v1)$myattri<-2
attributes(df$v2)$myattri<-9
attributes(df$v3)$myattri<-1
```

I would like to order the variables like this: v3 (smallest attribute, 1), v1 (second smallest attribute, 2) , v2 (biggest attribute, 9)

The approach by which you would order variables by name for example does not work:

```
df[ , order(names(df))]   # orders variables by name
df[ , order(myattri(df))] # Error in myattri(df) : could not find function "myattri"
```

I can access the attributes on the variable level, but not on the data frame level:

```
attributes(df$v1) 
  # $myattri
  # [1] 2

attributes(df)
  # $names
  # [1] "v1" "v2" "v3"
  #
  # $row.names
  # [1] 1 2 3
  #
  # $class
  # [1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: "I can access the attributes on the variable level, but not on the data frame level" Well, you didn't assign any attributes to the data.frame. You only assigned attributes to the vectors within the data.frame. (Remember, a data.frame is just a list with some attributes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
df[order(unlist(sapply(df , function(x) attributes(x))))]
```

- output

```
  v3 v1 v2
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
```

Comment: Try it now , you may have `R` version < 4.1.0 .

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Roland in the comments, you didn't assign attributes to your dataframe, but to the vectors in you dataframe. If you want to assign it to your dataframe you can do this: `attributes(df)$myattrib <- c(2,9,1)`. If you then call `attributes(df)`, you can see that each column has an attribute value. Then you can `order` you dataframe by `order(attributes(df)$myattrib)` like this:

```r
df <- cbind.data.frame(v1=c(1,2,3),v2=c(1,2,3),v3=c(1,2,3))

attributes(df)$myattrib <- c(2,9,1)

attributes(df)
#> $names
#> [1] "v1" "v2" "v3"
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "data.frame"
#> 
#> $row.names
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $myattrib
#> [1] 2 9 1

df[ , order(attributes(df)$myattrib)]
#>   v3 v1 v2
#> 1  1  1  1
#> 2  2  2  2
#> 3  3  3  3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
> df[,gsub(".myattrib","",names(sort(unlist(sapply(df,attributes)))))]

  v3 v1 v2
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
```